# Shape Sequences: What is the next

Tags: pattern, visual

Which is the next shape in this picture :

[image]

*Source: Iranian Ph.D. University entrance exam 2017*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following augmentation to the set of shapes

> [image]

The rule for going from shape $N$ to $N+1$ is

> Reflect all segments in the blue-red axis which are within $N$ segments of the red side. Then rotate the blue-red axis anti-clockwise.

Hence, the next shape will be

> The fourth one